# How to terminate javafx application on browser exit

Tags: java, process, browser, javafx

Hello I have a little big problem in JavaFX application with terminating java process when all brower windows are closed. I was trying to handle Stage.setOnHiding or .setOnCloseRequest and terminate all running threads and do Platform.exit in the handler body, but with no luck. First of all none of handlers setOnHiding and setOnCloseRequest are invoked when I'm closing browser. Also  setting Platform.setImplicitExit(true) does not cause java process to terminate when browser is closed - this works only sometimes. Sth prevents javafx process from being killed after web browser is closed. How can I detect what ?

Comment: Are you creating other Threads in your  application?  If so, how are they created?  Does your Applications exit method get called?

Comment: jewelsea, yes indeed there are 3 threads created by me, but they're deamons, so I assume they shouldn't prevent app from exit. I invoke Platform.exit() method but only If I click logout button, then the user is loged out from server, and then its ok. **JavaFX should exit when all windows are closed, the problem is that it seems the above does not apply when executing app embedded in browser,a handler for setOnCloseRequest will be invoked only when javaFX application is run as a standalone, not in browser.** I think the same aplies to setImplicitExit(true)

Comment: The last two sentences of the original question don't make sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me, JavaFX applications hosted in a browser always terminate automatically when the browser is closed.

You should implement [Application.stop()](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/application/Application.html#stop%28%29) to detect the application shutdown event.

Stage level methods setOnCloseRequest and setOnHiding are not the right methods for detecting an application level shutdown event.

Comment: Ok thank You, it seems You gave me solution. I did not implemented stop method. Thats all.